# Does specular light takes point or direction?

Tags: c++, opengl, specular, phong

Does specular ligh takes a point or direction as light?
If direction, theb should it be calculated such as **LightPosition - VertexPosition** ? Or just as manualy specified LightDirection ?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear; if you have a specific function computing the specular lighting, refer to its protocol for what it expects. But in general, the specular component of the Phong lighting model is defined in term of (unit) direction from surface point to light.

Comment: So light is a point and not direction(like in diffuse light) ?

Comment: If you have a point light, the light vector is the direction from surface point to that light. If you have a directional light, the direction to that light is always the same (that's the definition of directional light).

Comment: Both diffuse and specular lighting can be accomplished using a directional light AND a point light, all you need is the direction of the light relative to the surface.